# Downloading json response from an api link

Tags: json, download

I'm trying to create a script to automatically download json responses from this URL, https://api.data.gov.sg/v1/transport/taxi-availability for a personal project. I know internet explorer has the open/save as function but it has to be done manually.

Here's the site, https://data.gov.sg/dataset/taxi-availability. Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please take the [tour]. Also, have you tried anything so far? Please show your attempts so others can help you with it

Answer (score 0):

Try this [Remove Internet Explorer Open or Save Popup](https://jwcooney.com/2014/03/31/remove-internet-explorer-open-or-save-popup/)

This may help.